阿娜这次去丽江找的那个导游怎么样? Why in this sentence is 找 not 找到
HSK4 课文20 第三部分
There is a text question like this 阿娜这次去丽江找的那个导游怎么样? Can someone explain to me why there is 找 not 找到。找  means to seek, not to find, right? There is no mention of searching in the text, there is simply a guide with some features, so in my opinion, the question should be about the guide she found and not the one she was looking for.

找 here does mean 'to seek' --> 'sought and hired' = hired

Thank you all for your reply. I understand that 找 can mean both to seek and to find and when I want to be more precise I will use two syllables.

I checked out the textbook, and the author asks this question to the reader.  (I'll use the name in the textbook 安娜.)  What they want to ask is:

导游怎么样?

but they also want to clarify which 导游 they're referring to, so they use an attributive (a generalized adjective):

安娜这次去丽江找 + 的 + 那个导游 + 怎么样?

The only role 安娜这次去丽江找 plays in this sentence is clarifying who the 导游 is.  There's many ways of choosing an attributive so that it uniquely identifies the 导游, and the author chose this one.  You could use something simple like 安娜的导游怎么样？ or something longer winded 在丽江陪伴安娜的导游怎么样？ but they all essentially mean the same thing: 导游怎么样？
So, as for whether it should it be 找 = "sought" or 找到 = "found", it doesn't matter: they are both grammatical, and uniquely identify the same person (the 导游) and ask the same question (怎么样?).

There is no mention of searching in the text...

Indeed it does not mention this.  However, if 找 were an incorrect word choice here and 安娜 used some other means, then 找到 would be incorrect for the same reason (找到 is used to give the result of 找ing).  Nevertheless, I wouldn't interpret 找 too literally here (like how 找朋友 = "to find a friend" doesn't imply you're searching for friends behind the bushes or something), and the author is telling a fictional story, so if they use the word 找, then it's correct because it's their story.  And at the end of the day, none of this affects the question they want to convey: 导游怎么样?

现代汉语的动词“是”常常被省略。比如，这个苹果甜吗？

跑题吧，应该问另外一个问题。尽管如此，例子里省略的是“很”（这个苹果很甜吗？）。用“是”造句的话，应该是：这个苹果是（很）甜的吗？ （[名词] + 是 + [名词短语] + 吗？）。我认为大部分时候，“是”是句子的主要元素之一（它作为SVO里的V），不能随便省略，不过你可以换措辞、用其他的语法结构，以免用“是”。

对照英语的to be，汉语的“是”常常不出现。比如，这个苹果是甜的吗？那个导游是好的导游吗？如果改成，这个苹果甜吗？那个导游怎么样？句子中没有动词。

是跑题了。也不完全是。非谓语动词“找”和“找到”不是很重要。我只是说明，这个句子没有谓语动词。我同意你的答案。我加了分。

找的 ： find/found/finding
找到的: found
In Chinese, verb tenses are not always clearly articulated.
Verb tenses might be inferred from the context.
See below:

阿娜这次去(过)丽江找的那个导游怎么样?

找：found


阿娜这次(将要)去丽江找的那个导游怎么样?

找：find/finding



In summary:
In Chinese, tenses are not necessarily expressed in the verb itself.

找: get
找到: find
Maybe the tour guide Anna got last time was terrible, or fantastic, or very beautiful, or very handsome, so the questioner is asking what the tour guide was like this time.
阿娜这次去丽江找的那个导游怎么样?
What was the tour guide that Anna got this time in Lijiang like?
Is there so much to see in 丽江? Never been there!

Hope you can see the difference:
找的 - find

阿娜这次去丽江找的那个导游怎么样? - How was the tour guide Anna find for the trip to Lijiang?

找到 - found
= 阿娜这次去丽江找到的那个导游怎么样? - How was the tour guide Anna found on the trip to Lijiang?

In English if you have “was”, then you should have “found “. But it doesn’t fit in Chinese.

@PdotWang You are correct, it is quite difficult to make sense in English.
